# Cascade combo box query sorting

Tags: microsoft-access, sql

I have a question regarding ms access 2007 query sorting for the cascade combo box.

As i have initially 3 tables with names country,state and city and i want to have a combo box such a way that if i click on one country if USA i need to see the states of usa in the below state combo box and the cities in another combo box.

I tried using one video from youtube but the problem is like i followed the same meathod but it is not working in my ms access 2007 and it is not detecting any forms in the design view.And it is not giving any errors too.

The video i refferd is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpMyGlEInGs

Things are working till country and after that i dont find the anything in the state and city combo box please help me in solving this problem

Note:Iam using ms access 2007

Comment: This is a very complex thing you are trying accomplish. There are many places it could fail, so you are going to have to include much more specific information to get help. This may sound silly, but is there any data in the state and city tables? Also, did you establish the relationships, queries and the `After Update` actions? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: hello i got the answer it is not that complex and its working too the base is from the above video link i just posted along with my question and i just implemented the same for my question but probably we need to be careful with the key specificationa and the names which we declare to the tables

Comment: The base logic of the query for ms access in design view in the criteria we need to implement our logic [Forms]![Ourformname]![comboboxname] as in above example it is country and state but can differ based on the question

Comment: Please do not post your answer inside your question. This makes things very confusing, as if you tried it and it didn't work. It is OK to answer your own question below, so everyone who reads this will know what worked to resolve the issue.

Comment: ok thank you probably there is no other place to answer the question i do it in comments box so that if someone has the same problem like me can look and find the answer.

Comment: There is an answer box below the comments here. Put your answer there. That is what it's designed for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpMyGlEInGs 
This link above helped me to solve my question as we need to be careful in data types and key specification to the defined variables.

The base logic is in the design view as like in video the query he gave is like [Forms]![formname]![comboboxname] to which we want to redirect the values to it probably works fine